# Surrogate key for date dimension?

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle11g, data-modeling

There are 2 schools of thought:

1. Use a surrogate key, preferably in the format: YYYYMMDD as this will always
   be sequential.
2. Eliminate the Date dimension surrogate key and use actual date instead.

My Questions to experts on dimension modeling are:

```
1> Which design would you prefer and why?

2> How should we handle unknown values in each of the cases, Can we simply place 
   NULL in Fact table for unknown dates as Foreign Key can be NULL (if not why)?

3> If we need to partition fact table on date column, how would we achieve that 
   in case 1.
```

I am inclined towards using actual date and using NULL to represent UNKNOWN dates in fact table, as date related validation on fact can be done without need to look in to dimension table.

Comment: Why would you mutilate a perfectly good date? The question is: what do you mean by "this will always be sequential"? What do you achieve by converting key to YYYYMMDD

Comment: No I will not but one school of thought says add surrogate key for every dimension and add unrealistic value for UNKOWN Dates. This post is just to evaluate merit of each case.

Comment: No I will not but one school of thought says add surrogate key for every dimension and add unrealistic value for UNKOWN Dates. The advantage of this YYYYMMDD form is ,surrogate key is derived directly from dates without need of any kind of look up.This post is just to evaluate merit of each case.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that dates are sequential, too.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle is unusual in that its [Date data type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1847) includes time, and it takes 7 bytes. Other platforms usually have an independent data type for bare dates. SQL Server's date takes 3 bytes, PostgreSQL's takes 4, and DB2's takes 4 (I think).

When you use an integer in the format YYYYMMDD, you have to write additional code *somewhere* to make sure the values are valid dates. 20121332 is a valid integer, but it doesn't represent a valid date. You don't have to write validation code like that for a date data type.

When it comes to recording missing information in a single column, there's not *much* difference between the two choices. You either use dates that don't mean what the other dates mean, or you use integers that don't mean what the other integers mean. Encoding reasons in little number--where '1' might mean 'not provided yet', for example--means you have to store values that *aren't* valid date integers in the same column with values that *are* valid date integers.

But I think it makes more sense to separate the *fact* that some data is missing from the *reason* that data is missing. That means storing more data, and some people are reluctant to store more data.

---

I've found these two IBM Redbooks useful in designing data warehouses.

- [Data Modeling Techniques for Data Warehousing](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg242238.html)
- [Dimensional Modeling: In a Business Intelligence Environment](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247138.html)

[Anchor modeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchor_Modeling) is a more recent development. Most of the tables in a schema designed this way will be in [6NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_normal_form).

Comment: +1 not to mention the problems you cause the CBO and so on and so forth.

Comment: "That means storing more data, and some people are reluctant to store more data".
It's just 4 or so more records in the dimension: -1 'Unknown', -2, 'Early Date' -3 'Late Date' -4 'Not Yet Received'. Not a lot of extra data to add a whole lot more flexibility and usefulness for the user.

Comment: @Steve: A lot more complexity as well. This way you are storing two different kind of data in the same column.

Comment: I'm storing integers only in the column. -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2 3 etc. Simple.  The caption 'Unknown' is in a separate column.

Comment: Yes, but `4` means the "fourth date" while `-4` means "not yet received". Different kind of data. I wonder how aggregate functions will work.

Comment: No, 4 doesn't mean anything. You have to join to the dimension to see what 4 means, and assuming my calendar starts on 1/1/1908, it means 4th-Jan-1980.  How would it affect aggregate facts?  The ETL would build aggregate facts, and wouldn't use aggregate functions, and the 4 'Unknown' members of the calender would have their summary records, just like the real dates in the calendar. We're talking about data marts here - the point of a data mart is to make reporting fast, rich and flexible for the user.  It's our jobs, surely, to deal with complexity to make reporting simpler for the user.

Comment: I am thinking dimensionally here - not relationally.  They are very different beasts.

Comment: You can have multiple codes for 'missing' that have easily recognizable magic dates if you need to capture more information than just 'missing'.

Answer (score 4):

In order you ask:

1. Kimball bangs on about surrogate keys for dates, but I've yet to see a compelling technical argument in favour of doing it this way.  Converting to a YYYYMMDD format means you have to convert the dates or join against the date dimension to do date arithmetic.  Both of these have various ways that they can screw with query plans by .
   A datetime is 8 bytes on SQL Server and (IIRC) 7 bytes on Oracle, so it is a bit wider than an integer surrogate, but I don't see merit in this argument any more unless you have extremely large data volumes.  The optimiser just treats the date as a numeric value behind the scenes.
2. I've had requirements for 'special' values of one type or another.  Depending on how you want them to sort you can use various values.  In the past I've used this scheme on a number of occasions:

   - 1800-01-01 for 'previous'.  This will sort at the beginning unless you need dates earlier than this.
   - 9000-01-01 for 'ongoing'.  This will sort at the end.
   - 9100-01-01 for 'unknown'.  This will sort at the end.
   - 9200-01-01 for 'error'.  This will sort at the end.
3. Range partitioning on any DBMS platform that supports it (which includes pretty much any mainstream RDBMS platform) will work just fine on either date or integer partition keys.

I don't recommend using NULL for unknown values in a data warehouse as it will require outer joins to use the data.  This will affect query plan efficiency and puts a trap in the data for inexperienced players.  NULL keys in a data warehouse are bad mojo in quite a number of ways.

Another issue with NULL key values is that most ad-hoc reporting tools do not play nicely with null keys in joins.  Typically they will use inner joins, so rows with NULLs in the key column will break.

For most other dimensions you would use surrogates.  This de-couples the dimensions from the source data and allows you to bring new data sources into the system without disrupting the existing data.

In some cases it may be useful to have a natural key as the dimension key.  An example of this might be ISO currency codes or account numbers.  In the former case the 3 letter code is small enough that the overhead of using it as a key is minimal and the coding scheme is (typically) universal across all data sources.  In the latter case the codes are often numeric and short enough to fit into an integer anyway and typically universal across the organisation.

The prinicpal benefit of doing this is where you have reporting specialists using their own queries to manipulate the data.  It makes the tables a bit more legible to people working directly with the data.

Comment: Do you use surrogates for the Product dimension?

Comment: You do need surrogate keys for handling slowly changing dimensions, and I prefer to be consistent.  How does the user know the •1800-01-01 means previous, and that 9200-01-01 means error.  Pretty sure users would prefer my solution have having a few additional rows in the dimension to cover this.  I suppose you could have the additional rows with 9200-01-01 as the key.

Comment: @Steve - 'date' is never a slowly changing dimension.  You can put rows in the date dimension for the special values with something descriptive in a 'DisplayDate'column that has pretty-printed dates for the other dates.

Comment: No, I know calendar can't be moving, but others can, so I use surrogates, so why make an exception with Calendar. That was my point.  The main audience for me are report users, not analysts, and I typically work with Banks who have enormous numbers of records, so what seem like a small expense cost by using natural keys is amplified by sheer volumes.  I'm not a Kimball fanatic, either, by the way!

Comment: @Steve - you can do date arithmetic on a date but queries where you have to convert from YYYYMMDD to a date may not be sarg-able. There are also cases where having to join to a date dimension complicates the query. (e.g. find all instances of xxx where the most recent instance of yyy is between 30 and 60 days before it).

Comment: I'm not advocating converting YYYYMMDD into a date to do arithmetic.  The fact has 34563, which when joined to the dimension is date '2010-03-05'.  The date type representation is stored in the dimension.  You join from the fact to the dimension, then do the arithmentic on the DAY_DATE column.  If the arithmetic is to get all facts that fall in the quarter to date, you can have a column in the calendar called quarter, with values like '2012Q1'. You filter on CAL.QTR = '2012Q3' and CAL.DAT_DATE < SYSDATE.

Comment: @Steve What do you believe you gain by using an integer key for the date dimension?

Comment: answered this question in an answer - not room in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

1.Use surrogate key preferbly in the format of YYYYMMDD as this will always be sequential.

2.Eliminate Date dimension surrogate key and use actual date instead.

Use the first option.  You use an actual date, it will use up more disk, be less efficient to index and less efficient to join.  Also, if you use a date type, how would you represent 'Un-known date', 'Date not available Yet', 'Date earlier than Calendar Date Range', 'Date later than calendar date range'?

You can't use '01-01-1900' for all these differnt 'Unknown' type members of the calendar dimension.  Ideally, all surrogate keys should be meaningless, otherwise it is too tempting for report users to ignore the dimensions.  Dimensions add richness to dimensions, such as in the calendar dimension, the week the day belongs to, the month, the year, the day name etc etc etc.  Reporters should be forced to use dimensions by anonymising surrogate keys.

You should never have nulls in the presentation layer of a data warehouse, because they will force you to do left outer joins between facts and dimensions.  The whole point of a star schema is to improve query performance - doing outer joins goes directly against this principle.  Always replace nulls with unknown member keys like -1, -2 etc etc (assuming your 'real' member keys start at 1 and go up from there sequentially).

### Edit for Catcall

I'm suggesting using surrogate keys where the earliest date in your calender gets the key 1, the next date gets 2 and so on.  In a star schema, the fact is made up of surrogate keys - all small integers or measures.  You have to join to the dimension to see what date 1 represents. None of the surrogates means anything.  That's how you build a data mart.  How is the user supposed to remen=ber that '01-01-1900' means 'date not available' and '01-01-1901' means 'Unknown' and  '01-01-1902' early date etc etc?  Isn't it better to store these captions in the dimension and have surrogates -3, -2, -1 in the fact.  Then the user will see the caption 'Unknown' or 'Early Date' in the report.  Having a date type as a surrogate key is simply a mistake, and will limit the usefulness, efficiency and flexibility of the solution.  I know this through experience.